# Зацикленный список

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть БД, сущности и контроллеры. Так вот, в одной таблице у меня ссылка на саму себя,для выбора родительской сущности. Как мне сделать так, чтобы родитель не мог являться дочерним самому себе и не мог являться дочерним, кому он приходится родителем. Есть вот такое, тут вроде проверяется,чтобы он не был самому себе родителем.

```
Long resourceId = rResource.getId();
Long parentId1 = rResource.getParentId();

if ( resourceId == parentId1 ) {
    throw new RuntimeException("This is cyclic dependency");
}
```

Comment: В смысле запрет на уровне Java а не самой бд?

Comment: Да, что-то на подобии validate